# Xamarin - Custom Switch not working

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

So this is the very first time I try to create a custom renderer. I followed this thread here: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/32264/how-can-i-change-switch-text-color-android. I took a look at the first guy who placed an example code. I tried to use it with my own renderer but It gives the following error:

> Type or namespace 'controls' doesn't exist in 'saleskicker'

here is my code:

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using SalesKicker;

[assembly:ExportRenderer(typeof(SalesKicker.Controls.CustomSwitch), typeof(CustomSwitchRenderer))]

namespace SalesKicker
{
public class CustomSwitchRenderer : SwitchRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Switch> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (Control != null)
        {
            Control.TextOn  = "AAN";
            Control.TextOff = "UIT";
            Control.SetTextColor(Color.White);
        }

        if (Control.Checked == true)
        {
            Control.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Green);
        }
    }
}
}
```

However, the error didn't show up when I had the class inside a folder called 'CustomRenderers'. But I think this shouldn't be such a big deal. What am I doing wrong here? Can someone please help me?

Comment: So this is just the renderer in the Droid project. We also need to see your "CustomSwitch" shared control class implementation, which sohuld be in the shared PCL project.

Comment: I had to change 'SalesKicker.Controls.CustomSwith' to just 'Switch'

Comment: This is okay when you want to change all switches in your app. When you want just some specific switches to be different, you'd create a subclass of switch in your shared project, ie, "CustomSwitch" and then write a renderer for that, like you did already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to change the Color, you don't need a CustomControl. And then you can replace the default renderer with your own.

```
[assembly:ExportRenderer(typeof(Switch), typeof(CustomSwitchRenderer))]
```

Comment: Thanks, I was about to post this. I should sharpen my eyes next time!